# In which file, the configuration for jenkins pipeline provided through UI is stored?

Tags: jenkins, configuration, jenkins-pipeline

I wanted to know whatever configuration we do for jenkins pipeline from the UI, where does it get stored. If I want to parse a file that contains all the info Provided for jenkins pipeline, which file should I look into and where is it stored?

Answer (score 0):

All jobs' configs are stored in `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs` folder.

Take a look at `config.xml` file in required job's folder.